# Rolling 12 months for Reporting Services

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get 12 months of rolling data for a SSRS report.  I'm not sure whether it should go in my query, which is below, or in an expression on SSRS. The Field for the date and time is called `CALL_TIME` and is only featured in my WHERE clause.  Its formatted like '2016-04-01 13:46:00'.

Here is my query:

```
select

Street
Town
Incidents
IncidentType A
IncidentType B
IncidentType C

FROM OPENQUERY
(POSTGRESQL, 

Street
Town
Incidents
IncidentType A
IncidentType B
IncidentType C

FROM
(

select

COUNT(I.INC_NUM) as Incidents,

COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''A'' THEN 1
      end)
"IncidentType A"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''B'' THEN 1
      end)
"IncidentType B"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''C'' THEN 1
      end)
"IncidentType C"

FROM Table i

WHERE I.CALL_TIME  >= ''2016-01-01''

GROUP BY i.INC_NUM

) i
```

RESULT

```
Street      Incidents      IncidentType A   IncidentType B   IncidentType C
back lane       5                2                 0                 3
```

Comment: It will be faster if you filter in the query rather than retrieving all data and then filtering in the client.

Comment: Thank you, what I forgot to say at the top is, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to  replace your where clause :

```
     WHERE I.CALL_TIME  >= (now()-('12 months'::interval))
```

Comment: @whitz11 be sure to accept this answer if it was correct for you.

Answer (score 0):

change your where clause to:

```
WHERE I.CALL.TIME between DATEADD(Year, -1, getdate()) AND getdate()
```

Comment: That is SQL-Server, not Postgresql